# Request for an API with Axios - Unauthorized

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I'm trying to make the request for an API, using Axios:

```
const axios = require ("axios")
const httpsAgent = require('https-agent')
const https = require('https') 

const instance = axios ({
    httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }),
    auth: {
        username: 'username' 
    }
})
axios.post("url_api").then(function(response){
    console.log(response.data)
}).then(function(response){
    console.log(response.data)
}).catch((e)=>{console.log(e)})
```

but it displays error 401:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "url" argument must be of type string

    response: {
    status: 401,
    statusText: 'Unauthorized',
...
    },
    data: 'Unauthorized'
  },
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
}
```

Is there any more configuration to do? Insomnia/Postman works

Answer (score 1):

The code you've here

```
const instance = axios ({
    httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }),
    auth: {
        username: 'username' 
    }
})
```

It's already equivalent to initiating a request, but the problem is you've not passed the `url` and `method` parameter which is mandatory

So modify it to

```
const request = axios ({
        httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }),
         method: 'post',
         url: 'your_api_url_here', // important change
        auth: {
            username: 'username' 
        }
    })
```

Or you can simple follow and do

```
axios.post('url_here', data );
```

Finally, your code must look like this

```
const instance = axios({
    httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    }),
    auth: {
      username: 'username'
    },
    method: 'post',
    url: 'your_api_url_here',
  })
  .then(response => console.log(response.data))
  .catch((e) => console.log(e));
```

Choose either one of them but not both.

Comment: Hello, Ashu! Changed status to "status: 400, statusText: 'Bad Request',". Thank you!

Comment: Seems you don't need the http agent option in the request, can you please ask a new question or edit this one with the request data from the dev tools and the working data from postman

Answer (score 0):

```
axios.post("url_api",body,header)
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.